# Método POST sin observable

Tags: angular

Necesito llamar a un API con POST para que haga una acción pero esta tarda en responder 5 minutos.

component.ts

```
this.testService.sendActions(JSON.stringify(body))
```

service.ts

```
return this.http.post(url, data);
```

Me gustaria que simplemente llame al API y no que espere su respuesta
Pero no llama al API

Comment: No llama al api porque los observables no se ejecutan hasta que alguien se suscribe a ellos. Si quieres llamar y no te interesa la respuesta, simplemente suscríbete y no hagas nada en la suscripción... pero suscribir te vas a tener que suscribir para que se haga la llamada. A mi no me parece correcto hacer esto, pero funcionaría: `this.http.post(url, data).subscribe(() => { //do nothing});` Obviamente no tienes que poner el `return` en el método porque no vas a devolver nada. Sería un void que llamas una vez y cuando haga efecto lo hizo, nunca vas a saber más de él.

Comment: añadi lo de subcribe pero si no ponia el return me falla
  sendActions(data: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, data);
  }

Comment: `this.http.post(url, data).subscribe();`